# disk partition issue on windows 10

Tags: hard-drive

I have a problem in my HDD , I divide it already to many partitions , but when I call "diskpart" then "list disk" from my cmd , I found the whole disk as I don't partition it , what is the problem here?

[image: this the result of list disk]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only listed the attached disks.

If you want to see the partitions on disk 0 then from within DiskPart enter

```
select disk 0

list partition
```

See [DiskPart commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart)

Comment: ok it's fine , so why error code: 0x80070057 come through during trying installing windows 7 , take in mind I searched for this error and I found that it's a problem in my HDD

Comment: That is a separate issue.  You should ask another question for that giving as much details as you can of the error and what you've found/tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
>DISKPART
>List Volume
```

List Volume will display all the partitions.

Comment: `List Volume` will only show partitions with a recognized filesystem.  It will not show the MSR partition (which has no filesystem) nor partitions containing filesystems Windows doesn't understand (EXT4, APFS for example).  It also shows volumes that aren't partitions - for example reserved storage.